# How to select unmatched records in Single Table In Self Join

Tags: sql, oracle, select

```
EMPLOYEE_ID EMPLOYEE    MANAGER_ID
100         Steven          -
101         Neena           100
102         Lex             100
103         Alexander       102
104         Bruce           103
```

select the Employee Name & Manager Name select who not have manager

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Use an Standard SQL Outer Join instead of deprecated Oracle syntax, then you can add `where e2.employee_id is null`. Or better switch to `not exists`

Comment: i already tried that one, and showing no data found

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: @dnoeth you can still use `is null` with old-style joins.

Answer (score 2):

It could be much easier to do this without a join - just check the manager ID:

```
SELECT *
FROM   employees
WHERE  manager_id IS NULL
```

Comment: I want a employee name,manager name  And employee name manager name is Same column In My table

Comment: @Paunraj but if you want employees with no manager, then Mureinik's query will give the result you want. What is wrong with it?

Comment: That query will show No manager With Full Column tables But I want Only Employee Name And Manager Name

Comment: @Paunraj . . . Then just change the `select` to `select last_name, null as manager`.